# Cordova File Plugin: SECURITY_ERR

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugin-file

I have a hybrid app in production (iOS/Android) that uses Cordova plugins.  I have one Android user who is getting a SECURITY_ERR when using the File plugin.  This seems to be happening on a call to `writeFile()`.  The file path I'm writing to for Android is `externalRootDirectory`.

Can anyone help me understand why 1 user (out of 300-400) would have this problem?  The user is on Android 6.0.1 if that helps.

Some code is below.  The error I'm getting is `[Error creating file] – Error Msg: [SECURITY_ERR]`, so the `.writeFile()` catch is being hit in this case.

```
  //Handle Native download
  if (this.appConfig.isNative) {
    this.loggingService.debug("Starting to create native file");
    //Get base file path for android/ios
    let filePath = (this.appConfig.isNativeAndroid) ? this.file.externalRootDirectory : this.file.cacheDirectory;

    //Write the file
    this.file.writeFile(filePath, fileName, data, { replace: true })
          .then((fileEntry: FileEntry) => {
              this.loggingService.debug("Created file: " + fileEntry.toURL());          
              //Open with File Opener plugin
              this.fileOpener.open(fileEntry.toURL(), data.type)
                .then(() => this.loggingService.debug('File is opened'))
                .catch(e => this.loggingService.error('Error openening file', e));
            })
          .catch((err) => {
             this.loggingService.error("Error creating file", err);
             throw err;  //Rethrow - will be caught by caller
          });
      }
```

Comment: Have you defined [AndroidExtraFilesystems-preference](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#configuring-the-plugin-optional) in your config.xml? A Permission (android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) should be inserted into the AndroidManifest.xml  Also make sure that this directory really exists and if not creating it, like [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#create-directories)

Comment: Thanks @Blauharley.  I have not defined any AndroidExtraFilesystems preferences.  I didn't seem to need that for any of the other testing I did.  We have a few hundred folks using this without a problem.  There is a `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in the AndroidManifest.xml.  Not sure if that got added by default with the File plugin addition?  I'm also not creating a directory, but just creating a temp file in the root of the `externalRootDirectory`.  Would the create directory still be needed in that case?

Comment: In this case, no, you do not have to create a directory because you are already there where you want to be. Dont you get a specifiy error-message with an onerror-callback of a [fileWriter](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#write-to-a-file)? And please insert some code into this question.

Comment: Can do @Blauharley - I added some code details.

Comment: We now have 1 other report of this, from someone on Android 7.0.  So we've seen this on 2-3 out of 800+ users.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this one out.  [Looks like](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) after Android 6.0 certain permissions must be requested during use of the app (not just at install time). This is also alluded to in the [Cordova File plugin docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/), under Android Quirks.

> Marshmallow requires the apps to ask for permissions when reading/writing to external locations. By default, your app has permission to write to cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory and cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory, and the plugin doesn't request permission for these two directories unless external storage is not mounted. However due to a limitation, when external storage is not mounted, it would ask for permission to write to cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory.

So on Android 6.0+, when writing a file to disk the Cordova File plugin will display a prompt similar to:

> Allow APP_NAME to access photos, media and files on your device?

If the user selects Deny to this request, then the Cordova file write will get this `SECURITY_ERR`, even if the app requests this permission at install time.

Comment: Did you ended up writing files to cordova.file.externalRootDirectory OR cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory/ cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectorycordova.file ?

Comment: I currently write to file.externalDataDirectory for Android, and file.dataDirectory for iOS.  Seems to be working so far on a handful of test devices.

Comment: I am seeing an error, Permission Denied, when writing to cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, it worked for years and recent plugin upgrade made some changes and this error started happening. any idea?

Comment: Do you have android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in your android manifest?

Comment: Yes, I am using cordova-plugin-file and cordova-plugin-file-transfer plugins, these plugins adding android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to AndriodManifest.xml file.

Comment: I know there is a plugin to help with requesting android permissions (`cordova-plugin-android-permissions`).  I haven't needed to use that in my limited testing so far though.  The File plugin seems to request permissions on my behalf (for the directories I'm using).  Is there a chance that somone denied permissions when asked, which is causing your permission denied?  I've had to require people to adjust settings or uninstall/reinstall when they deny permission when prompted.

Comment: On Tab S2, I see 'Permission denied' and on Tab S4  'No such file or directory' error. Now I am not sure whats wrong. I may have to use the plugin you mentioned and add directoryExist method to cover these two cases. Your comments are helpful.

Comment: Interestingly, I'm now having some permissions errors on some file saving that I'm doing in iOS.  Not sure if that's related or a coincidence.  @chandravadan, are you doing any work in iOS?  Not sure if you are seeing issues there?

Comment: Yes, I am working with iOS as well, using `file.dataDirectory` as you are. No issues so far for me.